# How to get current post_id in function.php file

Tags: wordpress

This is my function in function.php file

```
  function getcity(){
    global $wpdb;

    if($_POST['state'])
            {
                $id=$_POST['state'];
                $district = get_post_meta(get_the_ID() , 'district', true);

                                     var_dump($district);
                $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM districts WHERE state_id='$id'");

                                                       foreach($result as $row) {
                                                             $district_name   = $row-
  >district_name;
                             $district_id     = $row->district_id;

                            echo '<option value="'.$district_id.'">'.$district_name.'</option>';


            }
     }
   }
 add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_getcity", "getcity");
 add_action("wp_ajax_getcity", "getcity");
```

I want to get current post id in this function to display selected dropdown value..

Answer (score 18):

Note that `$post` or `get_queried_object_id()` do not work until the first query was fired. So these options are available only at the hook `template_redirect` and later. But functions.php is included much earlier (before the hook `after_setup_theme`) so this isn't a solution.

A function that should work pretty much anywhere would be:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
$current_post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162869/52227) is a overview over hook execution order.

As mentioned in the comments `url_to_postid` may be heavy in some setups, so if your code is executed after `template_redirect` you better use one of the solutions below as they are most likely much faster than the snippet above:

```
global $post;
$id = $post->id;
```

or

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Comment: `url_to_postid()` is great function but for the some reason can be heavy on some servers.

Comment: Well its not a very compact function either ;). As mentioned there are better ways of getting the ID based on where in the code you exactly need it. But if you need to get this information very early in execution this may be the only working option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one my function what never fail.

I don't know why WordPress not made something like this before.

```
/**
 * Get current page ID
 * @autor    Ivijan-Stefan Stipic
 * @version  2.0.0
**/
function get_current_page_ID(){

    static $current_page_ID;
    if(!$current_page_ID) return $current_page_ID;
    
    global $post, $wp_query, $wpdb;
    
    if(!is_null($wp_query) && isset($wp_query->post) && isset($wp_query->post->ID) && !empty($wp_query->post->ID)){
        $current_page_ID = $wp_query->post->ID;
    } else if(function_exists('get_the_id') && !empty(get_the_id())){
        $current_page_ID = get_the_id();
    }else if(!is_null($post) && isset($post->ID) && !empty($post->ID))
        $current_page_ID = $post->ID;
    else if( (isset($_GET['action']) && sanitize_text_field($_GET['action']) == 'edit') && $post = ((isset($_GET['post']) && is_numeric($_GET['post']))  ? absint($_GET['post']) : false))
        $current_page_ID = $post;
    else if($p = ((isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p']))  ? absint($_GET['p']) : false))
        $current_page_ID = $p;
    else if($page_id = ((isset($_GET['page_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['page_id']))  ? absint($_GET['page_id']) : false))
        $current_page_ID = $page_id;
    else if(!is_admin() && $wpdb)
    {
        $actual_link = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        $parts = explode('/', $actual_link);
        if(!empty($parts))
        {
            $slug = end($parts);
            if(!empty($slug))
            {
                if($post_id = $wpdb->get_var(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
                        WHERE 
                            `post_status` = %s
                        AND
                            `post_name` = %s
                        AND
                            TRIM(`post_name`) <> ''
                        LIMIT 1",
                        'publish',
                        sanitize_title($slug)
                    )
                ))
                {
                    $current_page_ID = absint($post_id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(!is_admin() && 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && !empty(get_option( 'page_for_posts' ))){
        $current_page_ID = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    }
    
    return $current_page_ID;
}
```

This function check all possible cases and return ID of the current page or false on the fail.

Comment: I have tried this code to get the post_ID of a custom post type created using Pods Admin. Unfortunately, it didn't work. It returns NULL. I'm still trying to figure out the post ID of the current viewed CPT using a function in functions.php. I hope you have any hints for that!