# cookies not working in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've created a meta field 'priority_priority' so that I can sort post based on how many times they have been visited..least visited post gets more priority. so whenever a visitor visits the post the priority variable is decremented.but I want priority to be decremented only on the first visit from the same user so am using cookies but the following code in not working the priority is always decremented and

```
 var_dump($_COOKIE['visitor'.$post_id])
```

always gives NULL

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
       $priority = get_post_meta($post_id,'priority_priority',true); 
       if($priority>1)
       {     
          if(!isset($_COOKIE['visitor'.$post_id]))
          {        
               $bool=setcookie('visitor'.$post_id,$post_id,DAY_IN_SECONDS,'/');
               if(count($_COOKIE) > 0)
               {
                    $priority = $priority-1;
                    update_post_meta($post_id,'priority_priority',$priority);
               }
          }

       }
 get_header();
 ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <main id="main" class="site-main  site-main--single" role="main">
     <div>
         test
     <?php var_dump($_COOKIE['visitor'.$post_id]);?>    
     </div>
    </main><!-- #main -->

</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: What is the point of this check: `if(count($_COOKIE) > 0)` ? At that point in the script you already know that `isset($_COOKIE['visitor'.$post_id])` is false

Comment: yeah there is no point in putting that there.. I forgot to remove it..but it has got nothing to do with the problem I guess.

Comment: What is the value of `$bool` from your `setcookie` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**Add this Function in functions.php**

function set_user_cookie() {
    $test = "fyjfhjf";
    setcookie('default_school', $test, time()+3600);
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');


**To display**
echo $_COOKIE['default_school'];
```

Comment: yes that works !.. but am not sure when exactly init executes.. and how to pass $post_id to set_user_cookie function

Comment: To get Post Id Please check these two already answered question   First:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862495/how-to-get-current-post-id-in-function-php-file  Second :http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140753/get-current-post-id-in-functions-php

Answer (score 1):

I think sessions  rather than cookies are a better tool to solve this problem, for a couple of reasons:

- Cookie values are really easy to change in the browser
- `setcookie` will not work if headers have already been sent to the browser

By contrast sessions keep a more reliable account of the user's activity.  At the start of your script, start the session:

```
<?php
if(session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
```

Now you can save or get the info you need in session.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['visitor'.$post_id])){
    $_SESSION['visitor'.$post_id] = true;
    $priority -= 1;
    update_post_meta($post_id,'priority_priority',$priority);
}
```

You can also use a DB table for this, with fields `postID`, `ip`, and `time_added`. When a request comes it, if matching `postID` and `ip` are not found, add it.  If they are found, check that `time_added` is not older than 24hrs. If so, you can decrement priority.

Comment: @AkashGajbhiye I've added to the bottom of my answer, how to fix the current code.

Comment: the session should not expire when the browser closes, the session should last for 24 hours after the user visits the post..

Comment: @AkashGajbhiye I've amended my answer to allow you to use cookies as you wish.

Comment: still not working. but it'll work if I put the code in functions.php and add it to 'init', is there any other way to stop visitors from  decrementing  the priority of posts by revisiting or refreshing the page multiple times ?

Comment: Does this mechanism apply to all users or just registered users?

Comment: all the users..registered users are the ones who will submit the posts

Comment: At least 2 options come to mind: *option 1 >>* store in a DB table `ip` and `postID`.  When you get a request, select all records with that `ip` and `postID`. If none is found, add a record and decrement priority.  *option 2 >>* use a custom header. You can set it like `header("X-Visited-Posts: 123; 143;...")` with all the `postID` visited. get the header with `apache_request_headers()['X-Visited-Posts']`. If the header is set, and if it contains the post ID, decrement. Otherwise, set it (if it's not set) and append the post ID to its current value.

Comment: so if I use the first option,do I need to manually delete the records after 24 hour ?. the second option sounds better .. thank you ! I'll try that.

Comment: Forgot about the 24hr requirement. You can adjust either option to make that work. *for option 1>>* add a `first_seen` field to the table with data type `timestamp` and a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. It will be filled automatically with the time the record was added. When you find a record with the `ip` and `postID`, check that `first_seen` is less than 24hrs ago before decrementing, *for option 2>>* use the format `123=TIMESTAMP; 143=TIMESTAMP...` when writing the header. That way you'll know when a `postID` was added to the header and you can ignore or remove values older than 24hrs

Comment: sounds good..I just tried it using cookies its working fine. but the second option sounds more appropriate for this situation.can you  modify you answer so that it says to add the code in funcions.php.. I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: @AkashGajbhiye I'm glad you got it working!  Adding code in `functions.php` was @ansuman's idea. I can't take any credit for it because I don't even know how that works. The `add_action` function he used is not in the PHP manual. It's a WordPress function and I've never worked with WordPress so today is the first time I ever see it :-). I'll remove the last part of my answer (about why `setcookie` doesn't work since I was off)