# How to get tag_ID in WordPress functions.php and use it in function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'have some problem with my WordPress functions.php script.

When I go to edit Category of Post, I have URL:

```
/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=3&post_type=post&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dcategory
```

I need a function to update the field in category with ID from URL.

```
function overwrite_ratings_category(){
    update_field('field_630dbc7cf3fdd', '432', 'category_'.$_GET['tag_ID']);
}

add_action('edit_term','overwrite_ratings_category');
```

When I use number (e.g. 3) instead $_GET['tag_ID'] function works fine. But it's not working with $_GET['tag_ID'].

Is there any other way to get the ID of the currently edited category?

Comment: `edit_term` fires _after_ the term was updated, but you are currently only on the URL that provides the form _to_ edit it.

Comment: Tanks, so we have any other option to run function on save edits on category?

Comment: `edited_terms` for example would fire after. But I am not sure whether you will still get your `tag_ID=3` from the URL, not sure the edit form passes that along via GET.

Comment: Probably this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/39011662/1053190

Answer (score 0):

$tag_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [edit_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_term/) action, it gives your term id as the first param, you can use this param and do your job like the below code:

```php
function overwrite_ratings_category( $term_id ) {
    update_field( 'field_630dbc7cf3fdd', '432', 'category_' . $term_id );
}
add_action( 'edit_term', 'overwrite_ratings_category', 10, 1 );
```